# degree $2$ extension in a field of characteristic 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic 2 and $L/K$ is degree $2$ extension.
I want to prove $L＝K(α)$, $α^2∈K$ or $L＝K(α)$, $α^2＋α∈K$ , and $L/K$ is Galois in the latter case.

*My attempt* is the following.

Let $1,α$ be basis of $L/K$.
For  $α^2∈L$, $α^2＝mα＋n$, where $m,n∈K$.

We cannot completing the square in character $2$,
so we need to separate cases.

$m＝0$: $α＝\sqrt{n}$, so $L＝K(α)$, $α^2∈K$.

and in this case, $x^2-n$ is not separable, so the extension is not Galois.

I'm having trouble with the case $m$ is not $0$.

I want to show when $m$ is not $0$,

$L＝K(α)$, $α^2＋α∈K$ and **the extension is Galois**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $\alpha(\alpha+m) \in K$, so if $\alpha'=\alpha/m$, then $\alpha'(\alpha'+1) \in K$ and $L=K(\alpha)=K(\alpha')$. Moreover, $\alpha'$ is separable over $K$ so $L$ is separable over $K$. Therefore, as $L/K$ has degree two, $L$ is Galois over $K$.

Answer (score 1):

When $m\neq1$ you need to rescale  $\alpha$.

Hint: Divide the equation
$$
\alpha^2=m\alpha+n
$$
by $m^2$.

Comment: Vieta relations then give you the other root, and you can verify that interchanging them is an automorphism.

Comment: Dividing by $m^2$ is a standard procedure for bringing a separable quadratic in characteristic two into the standard form $x^2+x=a$. Over a finite field $K$ we then get the criterion $tr(a)=0$ for the existence of solutions in $K$.